# Background timer running

Tags: swift

I can't use the timer for more than 3 minutes while the application is in the background. I need to check the function every second, so I want to run the timer indefinitely in the background. Is that possible?

```
 var timer = Timer()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(zamanstateCounter) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: You _don't_ need to check the timer in the background. Why do you think you do? The app is suspended; it isn't running so there is no work to do, the state of the timer could not possibly make any difference even if you could check it. You can check the time and start the timer again when you come to the foreground.

Comment: If the question is how make it _seem_ like the timer was running in the background, then possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066625/what-would-be-a-good-way-to-handle-snoozed-functions and many many others

Comment: No, it’s not generally possible to do what you’re saying. But if you edit your question describe the broader problem, there are, most likely, ways to achieve what you want. (By the way, if you’re calling this function once per second in order to update some “counter”, that’s likely wrong, too. But again, we can’t comment further without a broader context.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until iOS 12, you could not been able to run your app in background mode, but from iOS 13 (beta) you can.
Apple has added framework `BackgroundTasks` which can add ability to do some task in background mode.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: you can checkout this video for detailed info of this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707#

Comment: Please follow the below tutorial to getting started with Background task
https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/ios-background-task-framework-app-update/